# Instantiating an instance of a class using an extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

The idea behind this code is that it uses an extension method to instantiate an instance of a class if that class is set to null. The code is simple enough, but does not work (it compiles and runs, but at the end the object reference is still `null`).

Can anyone suggest why?

The following code uses a simple class `SomeClass` that has a single `string` property.

```
class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}


static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static void InitialiseObjectIfNull<T>(this T obj)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        if (obj == null) obj = new T();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass someClass = null;

        someClass.InitialiseObjectIfNull();

        // someClass is still null - but why??
    }
}
```

(The discussion about whether or not this is an appropriate use of an extension method should be considered outside the scope of the question! I am interested in understanding *why* this approach does not work)

### Edit

On closer inspection this question is less about extension methods, and more about what is going on when you pass a reference type with or without the `ref` keyword.

The following function will cause a passed `obj` to be initialised for the caller:

```
static void InitialiseObjectIfNull<T>(ref T obj) where T : class, new()
{
    if (obj == null) obj = new T();
}

InitialiseObjectIfNull<SomeClass>(ref someClass); // someClass will be initialised
```

The following function will not cause a passed `obj` to be initlaised for the caller:

```
static void InitialiseObjectIfNull<T>(T obj) where T : class, new()
{
    if (obj == null) obj = new T();
}

InitialiseObjectIfNull<SomeClass>(someClass); // someClass will not be initialised
```

But...we're dealing with a reference type here, so what does the CLR do with the `new`d `obj` if the `ref` keyword is not used? Presumably it just gets garbage collected...

### Edit2

OK, we're going back to basics here. Consider the code below:

```
class Program
{
    static void SetProperty(SomeClass someClass)
    {
        someClass.SomeProperty = "Bar";
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass { SomeProperty = "Foo" };

        SetProperty(someClass);

        // someClass.SomeProperty now equals "Bar"
    }
}
```

Note: `someClass` was not passed using the `ref` keyword, but the value of its property was still changed for the caller. This is what I would expect to see.

However, change the `SetProperty` function as follows:

```
static void SetProperty(SomeClass someClass)
{
    someClass = new SomeClass { SomeProperty = "Bar" };
}
```

...and the caller will not see any change to `someClass`.

Comment: Re edit - indeed, but extension methods never use `ref` - see 10.6.9 in the spec.

Comment: One subtle point about your two functions: *both* initialize an object, but only the first actually impacts the caller. You said this all correctly, I just wanted to make it more explicit for future readers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this T obj` would need to be a `ref` argument. Since that's not allowed ([MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/sreekarc/archive/2007/04/25/extension-methods.aspx) or C# In Depth p258, Skeet), you can't.

I would suggest you not push this idea too far, though. It seems like a confusing application of extension methods, especially when the alternative is still a short one line.

Comment: While Jon Skeet is *almost* the same as the spec, I suspect "10.6.9 in the C# Language Specification Version 3.0" would be a better reference.

Comment: Agreed, it's not a good use of an extension method. I was curious however to know why it didn't work

Comment: @Marc: that's true. In my case, though, I have Skeet's book at hand, not the spec. I added a link to a more accessible blog on MSDN which might be more appropriate.

Comment: In vb.net, extension methods can be invoked with `ref` arguments.  My one complaint with that is vb.net allows things other than storage locations to be passed to such methods, with the same broken semantics that occur when `this`-modifying struct members are invoked in such contexts.

Answer (score 6):

You would need to return the value; extension methods aren't `ref` on the `this` argument:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T InitialiseObjectIfNull<T>(this T obj)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        return obj ?? new T();            
    }
}
```

Then you'd need:

```
someClass = someClass.InitialiseObjectIfNull();
```

Personally, I expect it would be simpler to do it directly... with either:

```
if(someClass == null) someClass = new SomeClass();
```

or

```
someClass = someClass ?? new SomeClass();
```

Comment: Then my calling code would have to be someClass = someClass.InitialiseObjectIfNull(), which is kind of mangled.

Answer (score 4):

Extension method is just syntactic sugar to this:

```
ExtensionMethods.InitialiseObjectIfNull(someClass);
```

You're passing `someClass` by value, thus assigning to it inside `InitialiseObjectIfNull` body will have no effect unless you pass `someClass` by reference, which you can't do in case of extension methods: you cannot pass `this` in `this T obj` by reference.

Comment: +1: it makes extension methods much clearer to think of them this way

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work because the obj parameter is not declared passed by reference. Unfortunately, you can't declare a parameter as "this ref T obj", it's not supported... I know, I tried that yesterday ;)

You could do something like that instead :

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static T InitialiseObjectIfNull<T>(this T obj)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        return obj ?? new ();
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SomeClass someClass = null;

        someClass = someClass.InitialiseObjectIfNull();
    }
}
```